# Custom Ionic Framework Popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an IONIC popup, See image below in the link.

I have an issue when i click on the buttons Arrange Coupon, It redirect me to the next screen. It is fine.But the popup doesn't hide. Please help me.

Thanks.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e55lzsl39

```
var myPopup;
$scope.showPopup = function() {
 myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

    template: '<a class="button button-block button-energized" href="#/redeem">Arrange Coupon</a> <a class="button button-block button-balanced">Add Coupon</a> ',

    title: 'Coupon Management',

    buttons: [{

       text: '<b>OK</b>',

       type: 'button button-small button-positive',

       onTap: function(e) {

       }

    }, ]

 });
 myPopup.then(function(res) {
    if (res) {

          console.log(res);
    }
    else{
      alert('here');
    }

 });
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add the image. However, The Ionic Popup service allows programmatically creating, showing and closing popup.
If you have a popup defined like this,

```
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
template: '<input type="password" ng-model="data.wifi">',
title: 'Enter Wi-Fi Password',
subTitle: 'Please use normal things',
scope: $scope,
buttons: [
  { text: 'Cancel' },
  {
    text: '<b>Save</b>',
    type: 'button-positive',
    onTap: function(e) {
      if (!$scope.data.wifi) {
        //don't allow the user to close unless he enters wifi password
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        return $scope.data.wifi;
      }
    }
  }
]
});
```

You can close it like this

```
myPopup.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @ashfaq  I have add image now.. Please check again

Comment: The above answer should help you with how to close the popup. Post the code for your popup if you want further help.

Comment: When i use ng-click on arrange coupon anchor tag, it does not call method. But when i use href and give path to the page it redirects me to another screen but popup doesn't hide. please help

Comment: You will have to remove the href. Then only ng-click will work. there you will have to use `mypopup.close()` and then make transition to new state.

Comment: but using ng-click it doesn't call function

Comment: Did you try removing the href ??

Comment: yes  <a class="button button-block button-energized" ng-click="gotoNext()">

Comment: and create function in the controller but doesnt work

Comment: did you create the function `gotoNext` on $scope ?

Comment: $scope.gotoNext = function(){
    alert('here');
  }

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?